# SQLiteExceptions not handled by ORMLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I've been particularly careful to handle all the SQLExceptions from ORMLite properly in my app, only to discover that underneath ORMLite android's sqlite is throwing runtime exceptions like they just don't care.

Is there any way to avoid having to handle Android's SQLiteExceptions AND ORMLites SQLExceptions?

Here is a sample stack trace from a method which catches SQLExceptions, but obviously not SQLiteExceptions.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.(SQLiteDatabase.java:1821)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:851)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:844)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadWriteConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at com.j256.ormlite.android.AndroidConnectionSource.getReadOnlyConnection(AndroidConnectionSource.java:50)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.buildIterator(StatementExecutor.java:189)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:153)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.query(BaseDaoImpl.java:245)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder.query(QueryBuilder.java:250)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at au.com.ninthavenue.android.notes.application.TagsEM.getRecentTags(TagsEM.java:229)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at au.com.ninthavenue.android.notes.activities.EditNote.loadTags(EditNote.java:257)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7308):    at au.com.ninthavenue.android.notes.activities.EditNote.onCreate(EditNote.java:119)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the proper answer is here in terms of proper ways to catch multiple exceptions, but I see it as a bug in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).  In most places (obviously not all) ORMLite tries to wrap the Android calls to catch and re-throw these exceptions as `java.sql.SQLException`s.   I've changed the code in AndroidConnectionSource checked into trunk to be the following:

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
try {
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
} catch (android.database.SQLException e) {
    throw SqlExceptionUtil.create("Unable to get writable database", e);
}
connection = new AndroidDatabaseConnection(db, true);
```

I've [added this bug](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3474501&group_id=297653&atid=1255989) to the tracker and checked in the fix to trunk.  It will be in 4.34.  Let me know if you find other places were ORMLite is not properly wrapping these exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Gray. Any idea when you will release that version?

Comment: I just pushed out a release recently and I usually wait a bit before the next one.  Find me from the ORMLite website and I'll spin you a custom version.